# Find and visualize median of a set of numbers when one value is unknown in R

Tags: r, plot, median

I have a set of numbers:

```
X <- c(-1,5,2,9,6,-2,-9,0,4,x)
```

x is unknown.

I need to get an equation for median which depend on x. And then plot a line chart with 'x' as x-axis and 'Median' as y-axis.

```
x = seq(-10,10,1)
Median <- "the equation"
plot(x,Median,type="l")
```

Comment: Such an "equation" does not really exist. Calculation of the median requires ordering the data as a first step. Why do you need such an equation? What's wrong with `foo <- function(x, y) vapply(y, \(x, y) as.numeric(median(c(x,y))), numeric(1), x = x); curve(foo(c(-1,5,2,9,6,-2,-9,0,4), x), from = -10, to = 10)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider `X`, the vector `X` (without `x`). `X` has an odd number of elements (9) and the median is the central value: `sort(X)[5]`. In this case, 2. However, as a number is added to `X`, the number of elements will be even and the median will become the mean of the two central numbers. The following `Median` function can estimate the median of `c(x, X)` depending on `x` being above or below the number with rank 4 (0) or 6 (4) in `X`.

```r
X <- c(-1,5,2,9,6,-2,-9,0,4)
sort(X)[4:6]
#> [1] 0 2 4
```

```r
Median <- function(x) {
    if (x <= 0) 1 else if (x >= 4) 3 else .5 *(x + 2)
}

curve(Vectorize(Median)(x), -10, 10)
```

[image: Median]